# Any open source tool for recording android mobile user interaction with playback like selenium IDE for web?

Tags: android, action-recording, uiautomation

I am looking for a tool to automate a few steps in android mobile on UI level like enable Mobile data/wifi, Download an app from play store, Sign in to google account, Download an apk using mobile browser.Can someone please point out which open source tool available on market is suitable.Also it would be great if it has record and playback feature like Selenium IDE for web testing.

Comment: Did you google for Appium?

Comment: @bish Yeah.I checked but I assume it helps to automate only the specific app, will I be able to do the following at parallel "Mobile data/wifi, Download an app from play store, Sign in to google account, Download an apk using mobile browser." It is more likely to test the whole device. Please let me know if I am wrong.I am new to android automation.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few available.  If you have experience in Selenium Webdriver then I would recommend [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/).  Easy to use but doesn't offer click and record.

Tools with click, record and run functionality, tend to be commercial some of the big names are;

[Ranorex Android Test Automation](http://www.ranorex.com/mobile-automation-testing/android-test-automation.html?gclid=Cj0KEQiA-NqyBRC905irsrLr-LUBEiQAWJFYTsYSQhCSoSxQ9EWxTXQ6sRxNcT_M59iujG7OW6vayREaAn3p8P8HAQ)
 and [TestComplete Mobile](http://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/mobile-module/overview/)

I can vouch for them both, but my preference is Ranorex as I find its data driven tools more accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout MonkeyRunner for android but It's not record an playback.

Ranorex is good for record and playback.